# Database Sql Query

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to extract record of person from table (employ) and I write query

```
SELECT *
FROM employ 
WHERE employ_Id=some_specific_id
```

Now my question is what this query does first, mean this will first go to the table(employ) and selects all the records and then apply filter on it or just go the table(employ) and find record of the employ with the specific id given after WHERE clause.

Comment: Imagine a table with 1 billions records. What would be clever to do? And then read about indexes.

Comment: Check the execution plan and you will know

Comment: If he's asking that, he probably doesn't know how to do that. Maybe give him some tips on how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

1) Table records are mostly stored in order of primary key (known as clustered index). So, when you use primary key as where condition then rdbms doesn't requires to scan table (all records)

2) For other then primary key. Rdbms checks if index is created on table and if can be used for your where condition. so, it can avoid full table scan.

3) If non of above is possible then full table scan if performed.

Comment: "*Table records are mostly stored in order of primary key*" - this is not true. In Oracle "index organized table" (which is the equivalent to a clustered index) are **not** the default.

Comment: That is why I used word mostly.

Comment: Well in Oracle IOTs are the exception, so the rows are not store "mostly" in the order of the primary key.

Answer (score 0):

When executing a query, it will look through ALL ROWS to see if they match your condition. This is why the more data you have, the longer the query will take.

If your condition is an index, as I believe is the case in your query, assuming empId is a primary key of that table, then the search will only be on that sorted index which will be much faster as not all the rows will need to be checked.

Answer (score 0):

1-> At first control will check for the table in user_tab data dictionary.

2->Then will check for column availability in the table if the column exists the check for the where condition.

3-> Condition may or may not true, the control will go to select columns